# Send CAN DBC messages via Ethernet/TCP with signal mapping

Tags: tcp, can-bus, capl, canoe

I have a configured DBC in CANoe with CAN messages and mapped signals. Now I would like to send the messages configured in the DBC in my simulation via Ethernet/TCP and still keep the signal mapping. The two ECUs are activated in the CAN and Ethernet networks. The transmission of general TCP messages works.

So far I have not found a working approach. Do you have any ideas? Are there ways to keep the signal mapping?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two projects that allow you to send CAN messages over Ethernet:

- [socketcand](https://github.com/linux-can/socketcand)
- [cannelloni](https://github.com/mguentner/cannelloni)

There are also Applications that allow you to send/receive CAN-messages using these protocols and that support DBCs:

- [SavvyCAN](https://github.com/collin80/SavvyCAN) supports socketcand (disclaimer: I implemented this support myself)
- [CANdevStudio](https://github.com/GENIVI/CANdevStudio) supports cannelloni (I haven't tested it)

Both will keep your signal mapping intact.
If you specifically want to achieve this with CANoe, you might have better luck contacting [Vector](https://www.vector.com/int/en/support-downloads/support/).